# If webrtc prohibits audio, will it still send empty packets?

Tags: webrtc

```
   mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
```

but ifound the webrtc can also send audio data,how to not send audio data when diaable it.
i want to save battery

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you set `track.enabled = false`, empty frames are still being sent. Though, bitrate is going to be really low, in my case it's ~1 kbit/sec for an audio track. Also, browser stops capturing audio frames from the microphone, so the only overhead you have is ~50 empty packets being sent each second.

If you still want to get rid of this small overhead, the only way to do it is to call `track.stop()` and remove it from RTCPeerConnection.

The downside is that when you need to unmute, you will need to `getUserMedia`, `addTrack` and then do another offer/answer exchange. So it's going to be slower that just calling `track.enabled = true`.

Comment: So, does I understand correctly that I can't stop a track without need to do another SDP exchange? (I'm developing apps using Chromium WebRTC, so methods names are different but general approach is the same; I may have more control than in the browser sometimes). My main motivation is to save server resources (mostly CPU), because in our app the majority of tracks are disabled most of the time. But we need to offer instant switch between publishers (who is speaking now), we can't afford any lengthy reconnecting/singling state.

Comment: Yes, when `stop()` is called, track changes to its terminal state `ended`. See the table at the end of the paragraph: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#methods-0 . To continue playback a new track should be added which requires another SDP exchange. One more downside is that once a track was added to peer connection, it will present in SDP forever, even when stopped. So if you `stop` and add new tracks often, SDP size will grow indefinitely

Comment: There are ways to workaround this, but it requires more information on your service's architecture, so that's probably topic for another question

Comment: My service is the online game where each player has 30 seconds audio/video time then publisher switches. The game driven by Application Server (AS), and for video/audio exchange we are using OpenVidu servers on Premises (since we have a lot of players and rooms we have multiple OV servers and one AS). We have Android, iOS and Web versions of the game. If you need something more specific, please let me know.

Comment: please, open a different question)